# ASP.Net MVC Checking Facebook Login status before executing code in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook JavaScript SDK to log in with Facebook,
the only problem is that the JavaScript code executed after the controller.

all i want is to check if the user logged in before going to the controller.

Any help?

This is the java script Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: '@Facebook.FacebookApplication.Current.AppId', channelURL: '@Request.Url.Scheme://@Request.Url.Authority@Url.Content("~/fbchannel.ashx")', cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) { window.location.reload(); });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) { window.location.reload(); });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/SaveAccess',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { A: accessToken },
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function() {}
            });
            var field = document.createElement("input");
            field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
            field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
            form.appendChild(field);

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();


        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/SaveAccess',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { A: accessToken },
                success: function () {
                }
            });
        } else {
        }
    });
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
```

i save the Access Token in a session, the problem is that this code executed after the controller code.

Comment: Please elaborate more or post some code. Don't leave things to assumptions.

Comment: I added Some code for you to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understand exactly what you wanted. Here's a solution for what I did.

You can call `FB.getLoginStatus` anytime to check if the user is connected or not.

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
              // user logged in and connected        
       }
    });
```

You can also add this in the `fbAsyncInit` to check user status every time the page loads.